# Dependency Graph in Spring Tool suite4 using Maven

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies, spring-tool-suite, dependency-graph

I am working on resolving duplicate dependency issue. While solving I come to know that using dependency graph it will be easy. But I am not getting how to print a dependency Graph in STS4.
I have tried this command which I found in Maven Documentation

```html
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

which is resulting :

```html
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ attache-ui-web ---
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.apple.ist.msol.attache:attache-api-entity:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Invalid POM for com.apple.ist.msol.attache:attache-api-entity:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.972 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-09-17T09:30:23+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone explain what does this result exactly mean and how to get dependency tree ?

Answer (score 0):

When you open the pom.xml file in Eclipse/STS3/STS4, there is a tab to list all the dependencies as well as a tab for the dependency hierarchy. It shows you all the dependencies that you declared in your project as root nodes and their transitive dependencies as sub-nodes.